# automorphism of fields

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups, finite-fields

let  we consider $GF(p^n)$ as a vector space over $GF(p)$, $p$ is prime. Also we want to have an invertible linear map on $GF(p^n)$, (automorphism of $GF(p^n)$). on the other hand we know that A field automorphism is a bijective ring homomorphism from a field to itself. I want to know what are the differences between these two automorphism? Can we consider them the same?

Comment: No, they are not the same. Being linear does not imply respecting the multiplication on the field.

Comment: so, may you please give an example for invertible linear map on GF(4)?

Comment: You mean which is not an automorphism of it as a field? Just multiply by any non-zero element different from $1$.

Comment: i mean how we can define an invertible linear map on a finite field?

Comment: You mean the definition of linear? Or examples?

Comment: define a invertible linear map on GF(p^n)?

Comment: I just did. The definition of being linear and invertible is precisely as it usually is.

Comment: if GF(p^n) is finite-dimensional vector space over GF(p), then what is the meaning of this: GF(p^n) is algebraic over GF(p)?

Comment: That it is algebraic as a field extension.

Comment: thank you, and my last question is that: if α is a root of  polynomial of degree n in GF(p^n), then  {1,α,...,α^n} is a basis for GF(p^n) ? ( GF(p^n) be vector space over GF(p) , for any prime number p.)

Comment: Well, if the polynomial has coefficients in $GF(p)$ and is irreducible over $GF(p)$ then yes, assuming you only go up to $\alpha^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, let $a$ has a minimal polynomial of degree 2 ove $F=GF(p)$. Then $E=F(a)=\{ k \cdot 1 + l \cdot a | k,l \in F\}$. For any field automorphism  $\alpha$ of $E$,  $\alpha(1)=1$. But $1 \rightarrow a, a\rightarrow 1$ will give us an invertible linear transformation.

Comment: This is a very good example. It is nice to know examples are plentiful: $|\operatorname{GL}(2,p)| = (p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ versus $|\operatorname{Gal}( \operatorname{GF}(p^2) / \operatorname{GF}(p) )|-2$.

Comment: in the above example , what is a and F(a)? and also minimal polynomial here?

Comment: As we know, there always exists a irreducible polynomial of degree 2 over GF(p). Then its splitting field E is exists. Let $a\in E-F$, then $E=F(a)$.